# Increase Attach Document MB Size vtiger 6.4

Tags: vtiger

I want to attach documents which will be more than 10 to 15 mb. Please suggest me how to increase the file upload size in MB in the entire system. I am using vtiger 6.4. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 10000); in index.php

Comment: You mean vtigercrmroot/index.php ?

Comment: I used it and got the error on the page Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/directory/public_html/vtigercrm/index.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

Please set below value in config.inc.php file
$upload_maxsize = 15728640;